# JQuery ajax url path (relative or absolute to what?)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run a php script using jquery's ajax. I don't understand how jquery defines the path for the script.
I know how to make it work, but i need to understand why?

The php script is here

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/videography/include/data/data_videography_date.php

// filesystem

D:\public_html\mywebsite\videography\include\data\data_videography_date.php
```

the jquery script is here:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/common/js/global.js

// filsesystem

D:\public_html\mywebsite\common\js\global.js
```

and im calling it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "videography/include/data/data_videography_date.php"
}).done(function(data) {
    // done
}).fail(function(data) {
    // fail
}).always(function() {
    // always
});
```

I notice that jquery append `http://localhost/mywebsite/` to the url. But how does jquery figures out the path?

Is it relative from the php script, from the jquery script, from WHERE exactly?
Even does it works, i need to know why.

Comment: It's relative to the location of the page, not the .js file -- so in this case, yes, the PHP file.

Comment: i still don't get why it adds http://localhost/mywebsite/ Could you please explain it so i can understand it. thanks

Comment: When the `$.ajax` call runs, what is the URI in the browser address bar?

Comment: This is just how URLs work, it's nothing really to do with jQuery.  You're running a local webserver (named "localhost"), and the PHP file is presumably at "mywebsite" inside that, so that's the address the browser shows, and which the ajax request is relative to.

Comment: @Pablo the url where im running is : http://localhost/videos/ but i use a rewrite rule like so: RewriteRule ^videos/?$ mywebsite/videography/videography.php [L]

Comment: Does using a rewrite rule changes anything?

Comment: @Marco No, but using an HTML `<base>` tag would. Do you use such tag in the head?

Comment: @pablo i do use a `base` tag. this is how i define it: `'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` and the results: `http://localhost/mywebsite/videography`

Comment: That is your answer right there :). If you temporaryly remove the base tag your ajax request won't work as is.

Comment: @Pablo removed the `base` and yes it did not work. One would think that if the base is `http://localhost/mywebsite/videography` then, the ajax url, could be `include/data/data_videography_date.php` relative to that base. But apparently, not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the additional information provided in the comments, the reason why `http://localhost/mywebsite/` is added to the ajax URL is because the following base tag is defined in the HTML document

```
<base href="http://localhost/mywebsite/videography">
```

In this case all relative URLs including hyperlinks will be relative to `http://localhost/mywebsite/` hence why the relative URL `videography/include/data/data_videography_date.php` results in `http://localhost/mywebsite/videography/include/data/data_videography_date.php`.

[HTML base tag reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Ajax is using localhost because your app is running on a local server.

Ajax will get the request origin from `window.location.origin` if given URL does not include an origin.

Comment: Did `alert(window.location.origin)` and i get `http://localhost` , so its relative to localhost...i think i'm starting to get it...

Comment: @Marco Think of http://localhost as the request origin. If you were on a webpage like Google, the origin would be www.google.com. The string that you give to Ajax can either be a path or a url (contain an origin or not). If it's a path, it will use the location.origin. If it's a URL it will use the full URL.